# asymptotic approximation of a third-order differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, asymptotics

I am investigating a 3rd order differential equation of the form
$$v'''(t) + X(t)v''(t) + Y(t)v'(t) + Z(t)v(t) +U(t)=0$$
It is known that the coefficients $X(t),Y(t), Z(t), U(t)$  exponentially tend to some constants. Please tell me the literature that will allow me to consider the asymptotic approximation of my equation in the form of a linear differential equation with constant coefficients.

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).